# IntelliJ terminal cursor shape

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, terminal, zsh

So, I am obsessed with Vim. I use vi mode everywhere - in all the editors and IDEs that support it. I use it it my browser ([vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb), [wasavi](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wasavi/dgogifpkoilgiofhhhodbodcfgomelhe)). I use 'hjkl' navigation everywhere thanks to awesome [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). I use vi mode in my terminal via iTerm under zsh. Long time ago I found [this little trick](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ramiroaraujo/dotfiles/master/zsh/vi-mode.zsh) that changes cursor shape in the terminal depending of what mode you're currently in.

Now, although it perfectly works for iTerm, sadly it doesn't work in OS X's builtin terminal. I couldn't care less about that, except it also doesn't work in my favorite WebStorm. I thought I could trick it and instead of changing cursor's shape I could try tweaking its color. Still didn't work.

Please guys, **help me to find a way to tweak cursor in IDEA's Terminal.**
Thanks!

p.s.: Some may suggest to change the prompt depending the mode, but honestly I don't like that. I still believe there's a way to change cursor shape or color. Prob. just need to find the right escape sequence.

Comment: do you use the vi-mode plugin for zsh? I use `ZSH_THEME="agnoster"` which puts "<<<" in red at the end of my prompt when I switch to command mode in the terminal. Unfortunately it looks like IDEA's Terminal plugin manages the cursor. Notice that it changes when you leave focus of the terminal frame. Unfortunately if you consider using the "agnoster" theme you'll probably have to deal with powerline fonts.

Comment: This question is too verbose. Do you think people really care about all those useless confessions? No. Summarize your question in two sentences.

Comment: @4ae1e1 on the contrary, the question directed to Vim aficionados, not only to get the answer for myself but also to help others. You seem to be in the opposite camp, so if you're not interested why don't just stay where you are.

Comment: @brain_bacon I'm using my own prompt theme. I know I can tweak it to indicate current mode, but I prefer cursor changing its shape.

Comment: I've been exploring the terminal plugin source to find where the cursor is set, but I'm not having luck. You can take a gander [in the community version](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/3f7e93e20b7e79ba389adf593b3b59e46a3e01d1/plugins/terminal), theoretically you could pull the terminal plugin source out and modify it into your own plugin.

Comment: **Update:** Might be related to [JediTerm](https://github.com/JetBrains/jediterm)

Comment: Kinda looks like they're just drawing a box for the cursor. You can try following the breadcrumbs from [TerminalCursor](https://github.com/JetBrains/jediterm/blob/90aa0513f4d9ab05c558a2bb68d40d3530f8202c/src-terminal/com/jediterm/terminal/ui/TerminalPanel.java#L675).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like Intellij terminal draws it's own cursor without respect to bash or zsh settings.

*Note I'm assuming community and pro editions of Intellij use the same terminal plugin*

[You can see the Terminal plugin source here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/terminal)

The terminal plugin uses [Jediterm, a Java based terminal emulator written by JetBrains](https://github.com/JetBrains/jediterm)

Most of the drawing of the terminal window is handled in [TerminalPanel.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/jediterm/blob/90aa0513f4d9ab05c558a2bb68d40d3530f8202c/src-terminal/com/jediterm/terminal/ui/TerminalPanel.java) and has a nested class called [TerminalCursor](https://github.com/JetBrains/jediterm/blob/90aa0513f4d9ab05c558a2bb68d40d3530f8202c/src-terminal/com/jediterm/terminal/ui/TerminalPanel.java#L675)

From the TerminalCursor class you can see that Java Graphics is used to draw boxes for regular cursors and blinking cursors.

[Code that draws a rectangle for the cursor](https://github.com/JetBrains/jediterm/blob/90aa0513f4d9ab05c558a2bb68d40d3530f8202c/src-terminal/com/jediterm/terminal/ui/TerminalPanel.java#L419-L431)

I'm still not sure how the unfocused cursor is drawn since it's just an outline, and I can't find a handler for lost focus on the frame.

Comment: Thank you for your substantial efforts and curiosity. I guess I'd have to tweak the prompt after all.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the terminal cursor shape from the dialogue below:

[image]

Now, this is a lot prettier to work with:

[image]

Comment: does android studio support it?

Comment: I have no experience with Android development

Comment: This is the proper answer to the question. It also works at least in Webstorm, RubyMine & Android Studio